# I created a new project in unity3d for a test and there is a difference when moving a cube or moving a spaceship why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the script i'm using for testing the movements. The cube is moving forward make a rotation of 180 degrees and stop. The spaceship instead moving forward it's just moving up then in the it rotate and stop.

Why the spaceship is not moving like the cube forward ? I guess it's something with the spaceship physics but not sure if it is the problem and what and how to solve it.

This is a shot video clip i recordered showing the spaceship in hierarchy and it's inspector same for the cube.
Both attached with the same script at below i also show in the video what happening when running the game:

[video clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9Q9TFlBGrk&feature=youtu.be)

The problem is that the ship moving up and not forward when doing:

```
transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
```

But the cube does move forward.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveObject : MonoBehaviour {

    public float moveSpeed = 1.0f;
    public float smooth = 1f;
    private float distanceTravelled;
    private Vector3 startPositon;
    private Vector3 targetAngles;
    private bool isRotate = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        startPositon = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (isRotate == false)
            transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;

        distanceTravelled += Vector3.Distance (transform.transform.position, startPositon);
        if (distanceTravelled >= 100 && isRotate == false) {
            targetAngles = transform.eulerAngles + 180f * Vector3.up;
            StartCoroutine (TurnObject (transform, transform.eulerAngles, targetAngles, smooth));
            isRotate = true;
        }  
    }

    IEnumerator TurnObject(Transform ship, Vector3 startAngle, Vector3 endAngle, float smooth)
    {
        float lerpSpeed = 0;

        while(lerpSpeed < 1)
        {
            ship.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(startAngle, endAngle, lerpSpeed);
            lerpSpeed += Time.deltaTime * smooth;
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't tell from the video - are you sure `transform.forward` corresponds to what you consider the forward direction for the spaceship?

Comment: The video doesn't show it, but most probably the spaceship really is upside down, which means it's x, y and z are pointing in a different direction than the cube's. So most probably when the cube starts moving "backwards", the spaceship is pushing itself into the ground as it's "backward" is "pointing down" (and ground I assume has a collider that doesn't let the spaceship fall through). Try using world space instead of local space if you want to move things around "as it looks on the screen"

Comment: Yes using transform.up seems to be working for the spaceship.  Why would i think about it ? I mean why should i think that up will move the ship forward ?